How do I make a docking interface in GTK?
I know this has been asked before, and the answer was GDL, but it now seems unused and outdated, so I thought it would be wise to ask it again.
The language of my choice is D, but it shouldn't matter much; I can also use C++ if it's really needed.
I want an interface with dockable panels, very similar to Inkscape and IntelliJ. I know Inkscape is also GTK-based, but I don't know what they do to acheive this.
With drag-and-drop, one should be able to detach docks from the left/right/bottom panes, split docks (top-left/top-right) and detach tabs from the main app interface. Docks should be closed by clicking somewhere.

For GTK3 you still need to use libgdl as tutorials show. If you will switch to GTK4, then libgdl is obsolete and you would have to use libpanel: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libpanel
